# How to use Dialogflow (Api.AI) Webhook in drupal

Tags: drupal, dialogflow-es

I have install Dialogflow (Api.AI) Webhook into my Drupal website, but I don't know how to start with it. For example: what is the URL to set into my Dialog Flow Fulfillment webhook? Which file in the Drupal Dialogflow webhook module should I edit to response to an Intent?

Comment: did you find any thing

Comment: I didn't continue